# Cut top part of an ImageView

Tags: android

I have an image view that has the height smaller than it's image height. The resulted image must be cut at the top and the width must remain the same. How can I do this?

Thank you,

Gratzi

Answer (score 0):

You should set the android:scaleType on your ImageView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I've tried that. But I couldn't find a scale value for my needs. Matrix doesn't scale the image but cuts from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

just set to Parent Layout `Clip Children = false`